# Как узнать является ли файл бинарным?

Tags: php

Как узнать является ли файл бинарным?

То есть...у меня есть в папке два Excel-файла файла, один имеет текстовый формат, а другой тоже xls, но бинарный, то есть через NotePad++ открываются каракули грубо говоря.

И есть задача, как определить что бинарный, а что текстовый:?

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать функцию
    string mime_content_type (string filename)
Она покажет MIME-тип файла (у Excel-файлов тип по-моему application/x-msexcel.

Comment: У меня эта функция не работает:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function mime_content_type() in Z:\home\imagecms\shop\system\cache\templates_c\981dce8e79ea0e46e3d13f157bcbd3b2.php on line 9

Видимо потому что (только PHP 4CVS)

Comment: В php.ini надо раскомментировать (или добавить) строки:
extension=php_mime_magic.dll
mime_magic.debug = 1
mime_magic.magicfile = "C:\Program Files\PHP\extras\magic.mime (или свой путь к magic.mime)".
А в httpd.conf вот эти строки:
LoadModule mime_magic_module modules/mod_mime_magic.so
MIMEMagicFile conf/magic

Answer (score 0):

Сам не пробовал, но что если проверить

```
is_binary(file_get_contents(путь_к_файлу))
```